# Mojang session server returns incorrect information

Tags: python, api, minecraft

```py
name = requests.get(f"https://sessionserver.mojang.com/session/minecraft/profile/{member['uuid']}").json()["name"]
```

I use python to get minecraft nickname from uuid. I had no problem before, but today this API returns me random symbols. Is this local or global problem?
[image]

I tried to use VPN or enother device. But every time sessionserver returns random symbols.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is global problem with mojang session servers. Now it works correctly, but everybody can't cog in minecraft.